# are the applications that I assign to specific ports also a server?

Tags: express

are the applications that I assign to specific ports also a server ?

I searched a lot but I can not clear answers. If they are not server at the same time are there seperate servers for the different ports. If you can help me, I will be gratefull.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOSsp.png)

For example in the above image are there two seperate server that are working ports on 3000 and 4000 or are there only one server and on this server there are two applications and these applications listen specific port? I can not decide.

Comment: Hi, the use of images for code/errors causes many problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you build an app with Express.js and then launch it on a specific port, it opens/uses that specific port to serve the HTTP server. So, yes they are servers.

Comment: This means that at every port that I build app there are seperate server in every port right ?

Comment: @CengizDemiray well, it can depend on the type of app we are talking about. if we are talking about microservices then it can mean different. if we are talking about a PHP server being published at port 80, express.js server being published at port 8080, an http server + websocket server being published at 8081 mean different. If your apps are seperate and they are published on separate ports then eys, they are separate servers. In microservice structure, they are kind of clone of each others. But i'm not experienced on microservices, so I can't really give you a clean info, if this is the cas